# Can I substitute unsweetened cocoa powder for unsweetened baker's chocolate?

Tags: baking, chocolate

I'm using a recipe for chocolate crinkle cookies  and it calls for 4 squares of unsweetened baker's chocolate. Can I substitute cocoa powder for the baker's chocolate?

[Recipe](http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Chocolate-Crinkles-IV/Detail.aspx?event8=1&prop24=SR_Title&e11=chocolate%20crinkles&e8=Quick%20Search&event10=1&e7=Recipe&soid=sr_results_p1i3)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's a very standard substitution. For each square (ounce) of unsweetened chocolate in the recipe, use:

> 3 tablespoons (20 grams) natural cocoa powder (not Dutch-processed) plus 1 tablespoon (14 grams) unsalted butter, vegetable oil or shortening

[Joy of Baking](http://www.joyofbaking.com/IngredientSubstitution.html)

I'd add that Dutch processed cocoa (if that's what you happen to have) is fine too, just be aware of your acid balance. This is the opposite issue, but it's relevant here: [Effect of undutched cocoa on baking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/45717/effect-of-undutched-cocoa-on-baking)

This too: [What makes the difference between domed and flat cookies?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/45123/what-makes-the-difference-between-domed-and-flat-cookies)

If your cocoa happens to be Dutch processed, ask another question about adjusting acid. Even though it usually doesn't matter, in *that* recipe, it just might.